# Dealloc NSString causes crash

Tags: objective-c, qt, nsstring, dealloc

I am working on Objective-C application. There I have this snippet:

```
QString result;
NSString *tmp = nil;
tmp = [activeApp bundleIdentifier];
result = QString::fromNSString(tmp);
NSLog(@"activeApplicationBundleId 2");
if (tmp) {
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
   //[tmp dealloc];  // <--- this causes crash
}
else {
    NSLog(@"do not dealloc");
}
return result;
```

I don't understand why it crashes. I have checked documentation from Apple and bundleIdentifier is property defined with copy

```
@property(readonly, copy) NSString *bundleIdentifier;
```

I also have read that I should be responsible of deallocating string. Why is this crashing?
If I use instead:

```
NSRunningApplication* activeApp = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication];
return QString::fromNSString([activeApp bundleIdentifier]);
```

Would I have memory leak for not deallocating the NSString ?

Just in case QString::fromNSString

```
QString QString::fromNSString(const NSString *string)
Constructs a new QString containing a copy of the string NSString.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, all of this is irrelevant and shouldn't be there if you're under ARC. So let's assume you are not using ARC, and do manual memory management:

- by convention, you're not owning the NSString returned by `bundleIdentifier`, so you should not attempt to release it*
- even if you were owning the string, you're supposed to release it with a call to `release`, not `dealloc`. `release` will decrement the retain counter, and only call `dealloc` if the retain counter becomes zero. As a rule of thumb, you *never* call dealloc directly; doing so may free an object that is still referenced from somewhere else, resulting in memory corruption and a hard crash

*) The `copy` attribute of the property definition is misleading; it's describing what happens when a new value is assigned to the property. Since the property is publicly declared as `readonly`, this reveals an implementation detail, which should not be in the public definition in the header (it would better be in a private interface extension not publicly visible). Feel free to file a bug report with Apple which will never get any attention.